# Is it possible to detect when an item in the contextmenu is not selected?

Tags: android

Could I detect if the menu pops up and someone clicks off the screen (closing it without selecting a value)?

Currently I have a checkbox that when clicked opens a contextmenu with choices. When I click off of it without selecting a value I would like the checkbox to disappear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be, have you looked into the [Reference Guide for `onContextMenuClosed()`?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContextMenuClosed%28android.view.Menu%29)

Comment: Unfortunately this gets called everytime it closes. It does take a menu object. Is there a way of figuring out whether the back button was pressed using the menu object that was passed?

Comment: If you set a boolean in `onContextItemSelected()` to true, then check if the boolean is true/false in `onContextMenuClosed()`; this would distinguish between the two. Just make sure to reset your boolean to false at the end of `onContextItemSelected()`.

Comment: onContextItemSelected requires a menuitem when I check that. How would I get that to send from onContextMenuClosed?

Comment: Declare the boolean as a member of the entire Activity, so it is visible in  both onContext...() functions.